# Why does Lightning-modal not recognizing label and not opening?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

So, I'm having a problem with lightning modal not opening due to not recognizing the label value on the aria attribute. This is the error I'm getting:

```
LightningModal - Templates with <lightning-modal-header> should define the label attribute as an attribute on <lightning-modal-header label="Modal Heading"> .
Templates without <lightning-modal-header> should define the label attribute in the Modal.open({ label: "Modal Heading" })
```

I've tried moving the label definition from the header element of the modal to the label attribute as suggested, but it didn't help; now I'm not getting an error, but the modal will not open (the html will be inserted to the DOM but without content nor z-index and positioning styling).
Did anyone encountered this issue? It does not reproduce in scratch orgs, only on sandboxes and trailheads.

Thank you all in advance,
Lior

Comment: can you add your entire modal template definition + the code you use to open the modal please.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was the problem. When I passed to the lightning-modal my parameters using the `open()` method, one of the parameters was an object, and I called its properties in the modal template. The problem was that sometimes that object didn't have the properties that was referenced in the template, and that broke the initialization of the component, and led to the error message, which was very misleading.
Hope that helps others who might encounter this error message in the future.